# Regex to find fields contains semicolon in notepad++

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

I have following file.

id;name;address

"1";"abc";"xyz"

"2";"pqr";"xyz;aa"

"3";"aaa";"bbb"

fields encapsulated with double quotes and separated by semicolon.
I am trying to find the field that contains semicolon (in this case "xyz;aa").
what should be the regex for it?

Comment: `"(\w+;\w*|\w*;\w+)"` can't this work? the only case in which you won't have a match is `";"`.

Comment: I made small change in this to include tab and whitespace in search. i.e. "([\w|\t|\s]+;[\w\t\s]*|[\w\t\s]*;[\w\t\s]+)"  but is high lighted all the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a strategy which might work for you.  First, you replace the semicolon separators with comma separators:

**Find:**

```
"(.*?)";
```

**Replace:**

```
"$1",
```

Now your dataset consists of comma separated quoted fields, and the remaining semicolons should all be inside fields.  At the point, a simple find for semicolon should land you on the matching fields.

In general you might need a parser here.  My find/replace trick attempts to simulate what a parser would do by escaping each field one at a time and removing the semicolon separators.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (a bit different from what I wrote in my comment): `"((?:[\w\s]+;[\w\s]*)|(?:[\w\s]*;[\w\s]+))"`.
I added `\s` since I saw you need that too (`\t` is included in `\s`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this `(?!:")([a-z\d]+;)+([\da-z]+)?|([a-z\d]+)?(;([\da-z]+))+(?!:")`

It can match `;a` and `a;`

Answer (score -1):

Try this: https://regex101.com/r/Z3Mnoz/2

`"[\da-z]+;[\da-z]+"`

Comment: This fails for the string `"2";"pqr";"xyz;"`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. it works for me in cases. but what if field contains semicolon at first ex. ";abcd"